# How to get only newly added data from the Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As i am creating the chat app, for it i am using the Firebase.
It works perfectly, only one problem which i am getting that each time i am getting whole list of data from Firebase, when new item is added or deleted into it.

What i want that , only newly added record should come from Firebase , not whole list of data.

Please check my below code for it

```
 ArrayList<ChatMessage> MY_ARRAYLIST= new ArrayList<>();

        MsgViewHolder viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MsgViewHolder.class);

        LiveData<DataSnapshot> liveData = viewModel.getDataSnapshotLiveData();

        liveData.observe(this, dataSnapshot -> {
            if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                MY_ARRAYLIST.clear();  //  I NEED TO CLEAR THE ARRAY-LIST TO GET THE REFRESHED DATA..I DO NOT WANT TO LOAD WHOLE LIST ON EACH TIME
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        ChatMessage bean = ds.getValue(ChatMessage.class);

                        assert bean != null;
                        MY_ARRAYLIST.add(bean);

                    }
            }
        });
```

As in above code i am using `MY_ARRAYLIST.clear()` to clear data, to get the newly added record.On each time  from `DataSnapshot` , i am getting the whole list of data, whenever new record added or deleted.Is their any method to get only newly added data NOT whole `List` from Firebase?

Comment: what you need to do is add a query to get the latest value added and not the whole list

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addChildEventListener()` to you `DatabaseReference` which will notify you on different callback method when any child is add/removed/updated/deleted or moved

```
databaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            // If any child is added to the database reference
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // If any child is updated/changed to the database reference
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          // If any child is removed to the database reference
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
             // If any child is moved to the database reference
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("FirebaseListAdapter", "Listen was cancelled, no more updates will occur");
        }
    });
```

The DataSnapshot in each callback will provide you the information of the child

Comment: In doc its says  it return only child data in DataSnapshot https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?authuser=0

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, in a real-time system there is no concept of the "latest" data because it's always changing. However, if you want to only display items added to the list after the page has loaded, you can do the following:

```
var newItems = false;
var eventsList = new Firebase('https://*****-messages.firebaseio.com/');

eventsList.on('child_added', function(message) {
  if (!newItems) return;
  var message = message.val();
  $.notification(message.message);
});
eventsList.once('value', function(messages) {
  newItems = true;
});
```

above answer original by (anant)

**(my) another solution**

if you have control over your database schema you can add a 'datetime' element in your object and store the value of the time just before adding it to database in Epoch format, then you can simply get the list of objects in newly added order with limit like this.

```
ds.orderBy("datetimeSent", Direction.DESCENDING).limit(10);
```

Comment: Your "another solution" really helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this listener `onChildAdded()` I provided a link to the documentation.

[Listen for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) for query on database,add on child as `date and time` and query based on that data filed after every result update the query to last sync date and time