# FirebaseDatabase onChildChanged returning multiple snapshots

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem that i dont get only the child that was added lately.

Here is my database:[image]

Here is my testing code:

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val newref = db.child("/Orders/ODbPagPuDFgGhj0l73lynD4Wdkr2/")


        newref.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildChanged(snap: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                Log.d("ac1234","${snap}")
            }


            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {           }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {            }


            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {  }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {  }

        })
```

Here is logcat:

```
2019-11-19 06:02:24.596 14991-14991/com.example.fru_vegetablesadmin D/ac1234: DataSnapshot { key = -Lu2y9uay-7G3gtFI4g3, value = {locationLat=33.95212290629996, locationLong=35.62042236328125, phoneNumber=+19823737, totalPrice=8,197 L.L., optionalAddress=, optionalNote=, time=19/10/2019 16:2 , order={Fresh Cucumber={totalQuantity=3 Kg, totalPrice=7497}}} }
2019-11-19 06:02:24.603 14991-14991/com.example.fru_vegetablesadmin D/ac1234: DataSnapshot { key = -Lu2y9uay-7G3gtFI4g3, value = {locationLat=33.95212290629996, locationLong=35.62042236328125, phoneNumber=+19823737, totalPrice=8,197 L.L., optionalAddress=, optionalNote=, time=19/10/2019 16:2 , order={Fresh Cucumber={totalQuantity=3 Kg, totalPrice=7497}}} }
2019-11-19 06:02:24.645 14991-14991/com.example.fru_vegetablesadmin D/ac1234: DataSnapshot { key = -Lu2y9uay-7G3gtFI4g3, value = {locationLat=33.95212290629996, locationLong=35.62042236328125, phoneNumber=+19823737, totalPrice=8,197 L.L., optionalAddress=, optionalNote=, time=19/10/2019 16:2 , order={Fresh Cucumber={totalQuantity=3 Kg, totalPrice=7497}, Fresh Eggplant={totalQuantity=200 G, totalPrice=700}}} }
```

I have no idea why it is returning 3 lines of data, i only want to listen if a child is added under uid ("ODbPagPuD... ")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is that data added inside `onChildChanged` and not inside `onChildAdded`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Because i only want to listen to to new orders not old orders & btw i am still stuck at the same problem and cant seem to fix it. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
        newref.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildChanged(snap: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                Log.d("ac1234","${snap}")
            }


            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {           }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {            }


            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {  }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {  }

        })
```

into this:

```
newref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
 override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("ac1234","${dataSnapshot}")

    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())

    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about that, but if i have multiple orders and someone new order under the same uid, i get a snapshot with all old orders and the new order. How can i get only a snapshot of the new order?

Comment: That's why i wanted to use ChildEventListener and onDataChange

Comment: @nickisra you can check the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443016/how-to-get-only-newly-added-data-from-the-firebase (This is by design, in a real-time system there is no concept of the "latest" data because it's always changing)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i got 1 more question is it efficient to use a subnode (order) and use a mutableMapOf to set value or just add another whole list of orders and give it an id and refer to it in my uid node?

Comment: it depends if you can easily access it. You can keep it a subnode as in your database since it can easily be accessed. Since the firebase database is limited you dont want to be creating multiple nested listeners for example so take that into account